# Azure IIS HTTP logs monitoring - NO RESULTS FOUND

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, iis-logs

I'm struggling with getting some very basic IIS HTTP log data available for querying at Azure Monitor > Logs.
Here are my settings so far:

App Service
App Service logs: Web server logging - File System

Diagnostic settings: Send to Log Analytics
log: AppServiceHTTPLogs
Log Analytics Workspace: LAWS-exitadviser

LAWS-exitadviser
Advanced settings > Data > IIS Logs > Collect W3C format IIS log files (checked)

---

The problem is that it always returns "NO RESULTS FOUND".
I'm totally lost. Does anybody know how to get/set it working?
Thanks!

[image: screenshot1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to query 'W3CIISLog' table if you have installed log analytics agent in the source machine. For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-iis-logs) document.

In your case, you would have to query 'AppServiceHTTPLogs' table. For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#supported-log-types) document.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks, KrishnaG! Going that way at least brings some results.